# Cakephp Mongodb

Tags: cakephp, mongodb

I want to use a enum document for my collection on mogodb using cakephp model:

```
class Profile extends AppModel {

public $primaryKey = '_id';

var $mongoSchema = array(
        'firstname' => array('type'=>'string'),
        'lastname'=>array('type'=>'string'),
        'adress'=>array('type'=>'string'),
        'tel'=>array('type'=>'integer'),
        'location'=>array(
            'city' => array('type'=>'string'),
            'country' => array('type'=>'string'),
            'street' => array('type'=>'string'),
            'zip' => array('type'=>'integer'),
            ),
        'created'=>array('type'=>'datetime'),
        'modified'=>array('type'=>'datetime'),
        'corporation'=>array(
            'name' => array('type'=>'string'),
            'description' => array('type'=>'string'),
            'link' => array('type'=>'string'),
            'logo' => array('type'=>'string'),
            ),
        'gender'=>array(
            'male' => 'Male',
            'female' => Female,
            'unspecified' => 'Unspecified',
            ),
        );

 }
```

By the way can I use the term integer for reference to a number field ?

Answer (score 0):

The `integer` type is defined as a supported [column mapping](https://github.com/ichikaway/cakephp-mongodb/blob/master/models/datasources/mongodb_source.php#L97) in the cakephp-mongodb library. Additionally, that type is mentioned in [this blog post](http://mark-story.com/posts/view/using-mongodb-with-cakephp) by Mark Story.

There appears to be no reference to enum support in the library's code base, so I assume it is not supported. You may have some luck integrating the [EnumerableBehavior](https://github.com/Kouno/EnumerableBehavior) library; otherwise, those options could easily be stored in a static array on the model class and manually validated in your application. Note that MongoDB does not have an enum field type (as you might find in MySQL), so either way your application would be responsible for ensuring data integrity of the field.